# Content Title Under a Flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox

Hello Im trying to add a title under a video for a site I'm building. I using an iframe in a flex-box. I tried adding another flex-box with just text and I can align the text with the videos above. Im very new to all of this and after 2 hours of trying to figure it out I wanted to see if anyone can point me in the right direction maybe. Thanks,

```css
    .box-tricks {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
      padding-top: 20px
      }
```

```html
   <div class="box-tricks">
       <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/BzGHbj7lquk" 
         frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
       <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/DGBBkqamB80" 
         frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
       <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/KRZtEXDeLVc" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
     </div>
```

Comment: It will be bellow the `iframe`? Where is the tag to wrap the title?

Comment: Yes I would like it below the iframe.

Comment: This was how I was doing it. <div class="box-tricktext">
    <p>Space Godzilla</p>
    <p>Phonics Monkey</p>
    <p>Jedi Flip</p>
  </div>

Comment: I placed this below the div I have listed above and the alignment was all off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap each iframe tag inside another tag. Not only to put the title inside but to make your CSS cleaner.

TIP: Better for SEO if you make the tag with the title as `h2` or `h3. Depends of the whole page tags order.

```css
.box-tricks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 20px
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-tricks">
  <div class="iframe-wrapper">
      <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/BzGHbj7lquk" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
      <div class="iframe-wrapper__title">MY TITLE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe-wrapper">
      <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/BzGHbj7lquk" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
      <div class="iframe-wrapper__title">MY TITLE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe-wrapper">
      <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://youtube.com/embed/BzGHbj7lquk" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>></iframe>
      <div class="iframe-wrapper__title">MY TITLE</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Ok cool so I would just add Css to the iframe-wrapper and the same for the ifram-wrapper_title then?

Comment: Yes if you want to stylize the title and the iframe as you wish. The position of the title (the main question) is done puting the title of each iframe inside the iframe wrapper.

Comment: So one more question what would be a example of the CSS for the iframe-wrapper if Im already stating what needs to happen in the box-tricks <div>?

Comment: Got it working thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to create a wrapper div for iframes and put the title in the div element.

```
.box-tricks { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;
padding-top: 20px } .title { margin-top: 20px; text-align: center; }

<div class="box-tricks">
  <div>
    <iframe
      width="300"
      height="300"
      src="https://youtube.com/embed/BzGHbj7lquk"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
      >></iframe
    >
    <div class="title">title</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe
      width="300"
      height="300"
      src="https://youtube.com/embed/DGBBkqamB80"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
      >></iframe
    >
    <div class="title">title</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe
      width="300"
      height="300"
      src="https://youtube.com/embed/KRZtEXDeLVc"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
      >></iframe
    >
    <div class="title">title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```